# Why does this program's interface disappear to the right?

Tags: java, resize

I'm working on a group project with my friends for a school assignment. Unfortunately, one of my group members made this program which was much worse before (I tried to fix most of the main issues). Only problem now is, the program doesn't load all of the text on the right, instead leaving ellipses (...).

I've tried modifying and removing setBounds, setSize, and contentPane, yet all those proved ineffective. I'm fairly new to Java all round, so please do go easy on my inexperience.

```
public class HomeMenu extends JFrame  {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    public HomeMenu() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1366, 768);
        setBounds(100, 100, 954, 712);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 236, 671);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setBounds(44, 5, 1, 1);
        panel.add(panel_3);
        panel_3.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 102));
        panel_1.setBounds(233, 240, 705, 431);
        getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel_6 = new JPanel();
        panel_6.setBackground(SystemColor.controlDkShadow);
        panel_6.setBounds(307, 235, 285, 164);
        panel_1.add(panel_6);

        JLabel lblWED = new JLabel("Weddings\r\n");
        panel_6.add(lblWED);
        lblWED.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblWED.setFont(new Font("Sitka Subheading", Font.PLAIN, 23));
        lblWED.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("");
        panel_6.add(lblNewLabel_4);
        lblNewLabel_4.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\groupwork_src_index2.jpg"));

        JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
        panel_4.setBackground(SystemColor.controlDkShadow);
        panel_4.setBounds(43, 25, 189, 298);
        panel_1.add(panel_4);

        JLabel lblBirthdayPartiesl = new JLabel("Birthday Partiesl");
        panel_4.add(lblBirthdayPartiesl);
        lblBirthdayPartiesl.setFont(new Font("Snap ITC", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblBirthdayPartiesl.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblBirthdayPartiesl.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("");
        panel_4.add(lblNewLabel_3);
        lblNewLabel_3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\groupwork_src_index.jpg"));  

        JLabel lblWeDoIt = new JLabel("WE DO nothing at ALL !");
        lblWeDoIt.setBounds(68, 359, 212, 40);
        panel_1.add(lblWeDoIt);
        lblWeDoIt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblWeDoIt.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 28));
        lblWeDoIt.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JPanel panel_5 = new JPanel();
        panel_5.setBounds(297, 25, 358, 185);
        panel_1.add(panel_5);
        panel_5.setBackground(SystemColor.controlDkShadow);

        JLabel lblMeetings = new JLabel("Meetings");
        panel_5.add(lblMeetings);
        lblMeetings.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblMeetings.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        lblMeetings.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_6 = new JLabel("");
        panel_5.add(lblNewLabel_6);
        lblNewLabel_6.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\groupwork_src_index(1)"));

        JLabel lblNewLabel_5 = new JLabel("");
        panel_5.add(lblNewLabel_5);
        lblNewLabel_5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\18060327\\Desktop\\index 3.jpg"));


        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setBounds(235, 54, 703, 188);
        contentPane.add(panel_2);
        panel_2.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 204));
        panel_2.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("ShadEvents");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Light", Font.PLAIN, 36));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(61, 24, 286, 58);
        panel_2.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Here to make your life harder");
        label.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Light", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        label.setBounds(78, 84, 188, 16);
        panel_2.add(label);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(297, 11, 123, 24);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\icons8-user-24.png"));
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(851, 11, 29, 32);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_2);

        JLabel lblUser = new JLabel("Welcome!"); //fix this user shit //unfixable
        lblUser.setBounds(890, 19, 38, 24);
        contentPane.add(lblUser);
        lblUser.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Light", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel();
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(258, 11, 29, 24);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
        lblNewLabel_1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\groupwork_src_icons8-search-24.png"));
    }
}
```

Instead of "WE DO nothin..." and "Wel..." (at the top right), it should display "WE DO nothing at ALL!" (Also, do let me know if the code doesn't work.)

Comment: Don't set bounds directly but learn to use layout managers. Setting the bounds directly (with a `null` layout manager like you're using) makes the elements have _exactly_ that size and if the text doesn't fit in (e.g. because of a huge font size) it will be shortened.

Comment: What Thomas said.  Remove every single line containing `setLayout(null)` and use LayoutManagers instead.  You may want to start by reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/.